# How to 'import' Vuejs component into index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, tags, npm-install

I use Vue.js CDN and I put all the Vuejs code inside a script tag in index.html. 
It works fine. However, I'd like to use [this](https://github.com/vuejs-tips/v-tag-input) component to add tags functionality.

But I receive this error [image: this] :

This is how my code looks like:

```
     <script>
      import VTagInput from 'v-tag-input'
      Vue.use(VTagInput)
      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
        components: {VTagInput},
        tags: []
        data: {
          errors: [],
```

I npm installed the package as specified in the github repo.

This is the head tag:

```
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="author" content="Seif Elmughrabi">
      <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="(( url_for('static', filename='materialize.css') ))" media="screen, projection">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic|Material+Icons">
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css"> -->
      <!--Google Icons-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="(( url_for('static', filename='style.css') ))">
      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

      <title>Your Insurance Policy Planner</title>
    </head>
```

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: @Mohd_PH I only use CDN for Vue, JQuery and Axios

Comment: You cant use `import` in browsers yet, nor `require`

Comment: when using CDN, a global variable should be created, so what matter is the order of the scripts tags, it should be vue, vue-tag, and there is no need to use import

Comment: @AngelSalazar vue-tag don't have CDN so I npam installed it.

Comment: well I just tried it and it works, check this https://jsbin.com/vutanigago/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Everything is in the docs!: https://github.com/vuejs-tips/v-tag-input

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant import another files in browser using 'import' you need to use webpack, however you can use this cdn to load the plugin in your html after loading vue.js file, https://unpkg.com/v-tag-input@0.0.3/dist/v-tag-input.js , here is a working example

```js
new Vue({
 el:"#app",
  data: {
    tags: ['foo', 'bar']
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-tag-input@0.0.3/dist/v-tag-input.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-tag-input v-model="tags"></v-tag-input> {{tags}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should load the script where `VTagInput` is located in your head, right after Vue. Then no need to import anything, `VTagInput` will be accessible globally

Comment: I added my head tag to the question. I npm installed VTagInput, it's not in the head as they don't have CDN, it's the only thing that I need to 'import'

Comment: I ran npm i --save v-tag-input

Comment: Just put the relative location or their CDN: https://unpkg.com/v-tag-input@0.0.3/dist/v-tag-input.js

Comment: --save add only an entry to the package.json. you will find the library and the dist folder in your node_modules